# SQL Server 2008 : FROM clause syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My code returns a syntax error on L42 (the from clause). I've looked and looked and to me, the syntax looks correct for the `FROM`.

The top part of the code creates a temp table 'subproducts'. Then I want to pull data from DB tables & pull relevant details from the new temp table.

Any ideas?

```
drop table ##subproducts;

SELECT 
  F1.[OrderNo]
  ,F1.[OrderSeqNo]
  ,F1.[OrderLineNo]
  ,sum(F1.[LineCost]) as LineCost
  ,sum(F1.[NetCost]) as NetCost
  ,sum(F1.[OrderNet]) as OrderNet
INTO 
   ##subproducts
FROM 
   [UFPData].[dbo].[SalesStats] F1
WHERE 
   F1.MainProd = 'S'
GROUP BY 
   F1.OrderNo, F1.OrderSeqNo, F1.OrderLineNo;

SELECT * 
FROM SalesStats F1
LEFT OUTER JOIN ##subproducts F2 ON F1.OrderNo = F2.OrderNo 
                                 AND F1.OrderSeqNo = F2.Orderseqno 
                                 AND F1.OrderLineNo = F2.OrderLineNo
WHERE YEAR(InvDate) = 2015
  AND MONTH(InvDate) = 5
  AND CustNo = 100382
  AND MainProd = 'Y';

SELECT 
    ContractInfo.CONTRNO,
    ContractInfo.CONTRDESC,
    repcode, 
    RepName,
    PriceAgreement,
    ordercycle, 
    SalesStats.CustNo,
    Customer.CustName,
    SalesStats.InvDate, 
    SalesStats.InvoiceNo, 
    salesstats.ProdCode,
    Price as ContractPrice,
    subproduct.LineCost as LineCost,
    subproduct.NetCost as NetCost,
    subproduct.OrderNet as OrderNet,
    contractinfo.NETCOST as BidPrice,
    contractinfo.NETCOST* SUM(quantity) as BidCost,
FROM 
    UFPData.dbo.SalesStats 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    ##subproducts ON UFPData.dbo.SalesStats.ProdCode = ##subproducts.ProdCode,
    UFPData.dbo.SalesStats 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    UFPData.dbo.Customer ON UFPData.dbo.SalesStats.CustNo = UFPData.dbo.Customer.CustNo, UFPData.dbo.SalesStats 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Pricing.dbo.InvManCen ON UFPData.dbo.SalesStats.ProdCode = Pricing.dbo.invmancen.UFPCODE, UFPData.dbo.SalesStats 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    UFPData.dbo.ContractInfo ON UFPData.dbo.Customer.CustNo = UFPData.dbo.ContractInfo.CUSTNO 
                             AND UFPData.dbo.salesstats.prodcode = UFPData.dbo.contractinfo.prodcode,
WHERE
    invdate BETWEEN '2015-05-01' and '2015-05-31'
    AND TeamCode IN ('tm1','tm2','tm3')
    AND ContractInfo.CONTRNO IN ('1500','1502','1503','1504','1505','1506','701','702','703','705','141',
'712',  '713',  '714',  '715',  '716',  '717',  '718',  '719',  '730',  '731',  '732') or CONTRNO between '3000' and '3049')
--and left(ordercycle,1) <> 'c'
GROUP BY
    ContractInfo.CONTRNO,
    repcode, 
    RepName,
    SalesStats.CustNo,
    Customer.CustName, 
    SalesStats.InvDate,
    salesstats.ProdCode,
    Price,
    contractinfo.NETCOST,
    SalesStats.InvoiceNo,
    InvManCen.PS98,
    ContractInfo.CONTRDESC,
    ordercycle,
    PriceAgreement,

case
when invdate >   ('20' + LEFT(ENDDATE,2)+ '-'+ SUBSTRING(cast(ENDDATE as varchar(6)),3,2)+ '-'+ SUBSTRING(cast(ENDDATE as varchar(6)),5,2)) then 'Expired' else 'Live'  end;
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What if ##subproducts doesn't exist yet?

Comment: yes, you have an extra `,` before the `FROM`: `as BidCost, FROM `

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look right to me:

```
FROM 
UFPData.dbo.SalesStats right outer join ##subproducts on UFPData.dbo.SalesStats.ProdCode = ##subproducts.ProdCode,
UFPData.dbo.SalesStats left outer join UFPData.dbo.Customer on UFPData.dbo.SalesStats.CustNo = UFPData.dbo.Customer.CustNo,
UFPData.dbo.SalesStats left outer join Pricing.dbo.InvManCen on UFPData.dbo.SalesStats.ProdCode = Pricing.dbo.invmancen.UFPCODE,
UFPData.dbo.SalesStats right outer join UFPData.dbo.ContractInfo on UFPData.dbo.Customer.CustNo = UFPData.dbo.ContractInfo.CUSTNO and UFPData.dbo.salesstats.prodcode = UFPData.dbo.contractinfo.prodcode,
```

Usually the format is something like this:

```
FROM
  TableName
  INNER JOIN SomeOtherTable...
  INNER JOIN AnotherTable...
```

Note that the first table is mentioned *once*, not before every join.  You also seem to have errant commas after each join, which isn't syntactically correct.  I think you want this:

```
FROM 
UFPData.dbo.SalesStats
right outer join ##subproducts on UFPData.dbo.SalesStats.ProdCode = ##subproducts.ProdCode
left outer join UFPData.dbo.Customer on UFPData.dbo.SalesStats.CustNo = UFPData.dbo.Customer.CustNo
left outer join Pricing.dbo.InvManCen on UFPData.dbo.SalesStats.ProdCode = Pricing.dbo.invmancen.UFPCODE
right outer join UFPData.dbo.ContractInfo on UFPData.dbo.Customer.CustNo = UFPData.dbo.ContractInfo.CUSTNO and UFPData.dbo.salesstats.prodcode = UFPData.dbo.contractinfo.prodcode
```

There could very well be more syntax errors throughout your query.  I recommend formatting the code a little more cleanly to more easily find them.  For example, contrast the above with something like this:

```
FROM 
    UFPData.dbo.SalesStats
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN ##subproducts
        ON UFPData.dbo.SalesStats.ProdCode = ##subproducts.ProdCode
    LEFT OUTER JOIN UFPData.dbo.Customer
        ON UFPData.dbo.SalesStats.CustNo = UFPData.dbo.Customer.CustNo
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Pricing.dbo.InvManCen
        ON UFPData.dbo.SalesStats.ProdCode = Pricing.dbo.invmancen.UFPCODE
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN UFPData.dbo.ContractInfo
        ON UFPData.dbo.Customer.CustNo = UFPData.dbo.ContractInfo.CUSTNO
        AND UFPData.dbo.salesstats.prodcode = UFPData.dbo.contractinfo.prodcode
```

It's a small change, and often a matter of personal preference, but well formatted code brings about a number of advantages.  Less horizontal scrolling makes it easier to see the relevant code in a single glance, line breaks for specific keywords and clauses makes it easier to spot errant commas, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think should be valid syntax for what you've provided, please try it and compare it to the original as there were multiple errors:

```
DROP TABLE ##subproducts;

SELECT  F1.[OrderNo] ,
        F1.[OrderSeqNo] ,
        F1.[OrderLineNo] ,
        SUM(F1.[LineCost]) AS LineCost ,
        SUM(F1.[NetCost]) AS NetCost ,
        SUM(F1.[OrderNet]) AS OrderNet
INTO    ##subproducts
FROM    [UFPData].[dbo].[SalesStats] F1
WHERE   F1.MainProd = 'S'
GROUP BY F1.OrderNo ,
        F1.OrderSeqNo ,
        F1.OrderLineNo;

SELECT  *
FROM    SalesStats F1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ##subproducts F2 ON F1.OrderNo = F2.OrderNo
                                            AND F1.OrderSeqNo = F2.Orderseqno
                                            AND F1.OrderLineNo = F2.OrderLineNo
WHERE   YEAR(InvDate) = 2015
        AND MONTH(InvDate) = 5
        AND CustNo = 100382
        AND MainProd = 'Y';

SELECT  ContractInfo.CONTRNO ,
        ContractInfo.CONTRDESC ,
        repcode ,
        RepName ,
        PriceAgreement ,
        ordercycle ,
        SalesStats.CustNo ,
        Customer.CustName ,
        SalesStats.InvDate ,
        SalesStats.InvoiceNo ,
        SalesStats.ProdCode ,
        Price AS ContractPrice ,
        subproduct.LineCost AS LineCost ,
        subproduct.NetCost AS NetCost ,
        subproduct.OrderNet AS OrderNet ,
        ContractInfo.NetCost AS BidPrice ,
        ContractInfo.NetCost * SUM(quantity) AS BidCost
FROM    UFPData.dbo.SalesStats
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN ##subproducts ON UFPData.dbo.SalesStats.ProdCode = ##subproducts.ProdCode
        LEFT OUTER JOIN UFPData.dbo.Customer ON UFPData.dbo.SalesStats.CustNo = UFPData.dbo.Customer.CustNo
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Pricing.dbo.InvManCen ON UFPData.dbo.SalesStats.ProdCode = Pricing.dbo.invmancen.UFPCODE
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN UFPData.dbo.ContractInfo ON UFPData.dbo.Customer.CustNo = UFPData.dbo.ContractInfo.CUSTNO
                                                     AND UFPData.dbo.salesstats.prodcode = UFPData.dbo.contractinfo.prodcode
WHERE   invdate BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-05-31'
        AND TeamCode IN ( 'tm1', 'tm2', 'tm3' )
        AND (ContractInfo.CONTRNO IN ( '1500', '1502', '1503', '1504', '1505',
                                      '1506', '701', '702', '703', '705',
                                      '141', '712', '713', '714', '715', '716',
                                      '717', '718', '719', '730', '731', '732' )
        OR CONTRNO BETWEEN '3000' AND '3049')
GROUP BY ContractInfo.CONTRNO ,
        repcode ,
        RepName ,
        SalesStats.CustNo ,
        Customer.CustName ,
        SalesStats.InvDate ,
        SalesStats.ProdCode ,
        Price ,
        ContractInfo.NetCost ,
        SalesStats.InvoiceNo ,
        InvManCen.PS98 ,
        ContractInfo.CONTRDESC ,
        ordercycle ,
        PriceAgreement ,
        CASE WHEN invdate > ( '20' + LEFT(ENDDATE, 2) + '-'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(ENDDATE AS VARCHAR(6)), 3, 2)
                              + '-' + SUBSTRING(CAST(ENDDATE AS VARCHAR(6)), 5,
                                                2) ) THEN 'Expired'
             ELSE 'Live'
        END;
```

Comment: Yes I am very new.  This is partially some code I had picked up from a the person who did the job previous and some code from IT that I was asked to put together.  Majority of this content is above my head.  I think the issue with it running was a , at the end of the line previous to the FROM statement (42 I think).  Something that has dawned on me as I'm using AdventureWorks DB and my SQL book.

Comment: @IainW have you got it working now or do you have further queries?